# Intent not working in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery, onactivityresult

I am trying to get image from gallery from my 1st Activity and want the resulted image in the ImageView of second activity.

Here is the Code For 1st Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageVew = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public void useGalleryMethod(View view) {
    //this is for picking Image from Gallery or file
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

onActivityResult() in 1st Class:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        try {
            //this is for picking Image from Gallery or file
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            imageVew.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Bitmap",bitmap);
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Code For Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

    Intent getIntentInfo = getIntent();

    if(getIntentInfo != null){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntentInfo.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

The App is running properly and showing the gallery image in ImageView of 1st Class Only and not going to 2nd Activity using the Intent in onActivityResult method.

Please Let  Me know whats wrong with my code? ? 
or is there any other way and I am not going in the right direction ?

Comment: check answer, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method which is more convenient that Parcelable you used:

method 1: Your can save that to sd card and retrieve.

OR
method 2:

**Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-**

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

**Pass Byte Array with Intent:-**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Get Bitmap from ByteArray received in bundle:-**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

I dont have any drawable and ic.launcher is giving error (Can't resolve symbol ic.launcher)

Comment: Problem Solved:
I use Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());

instead of 

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

and rest of your code to convert bitmap into byte array and the problem resoled.

Thanks

Comment: My pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

In `onActivityResult()` of first activity replace this -

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        try {
            //this is for picking Image from Gallery or file
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            imageVew.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // Send Image URI istead
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageUri", data.getData().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And on Second Activity do something like -

```
if(getIntentInfo != null){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
            Uri.parse(getIntentInfo.getStringExtra("imageUri")));
        imageVew.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else{
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
            Uri.parse(getIntentInfo.getString("imageUri")));

Unable to use .getString("imageUri") with Intent object "getIntentInfo"

Comment: No! Still Not Working. But Thank you for your Time and help.

My Problem has been resolved!